# Tikz mindmap baloon size

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a mindmap with tikz for my notes on political philosophy but the child nodes become so little that I cannot read what it's inside.
Here's an example:
[image]

As you can see the first nodes are easily readeble unlike the last ones.

This is the code

```
    \begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
  \chapter*{Liberal Equality}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!10, 
    level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45},]


\node{Rawls}
    child[concept color=red!60]{node{He's in opposition with}
        child{node{Utilitarism}}
        child{node{Intuitionism}}
    }
    child[concept color=blue!60]{node{Two main arguments}
        child{node{Intuitive argument}
            child{node{Equality of opportunity}
                child{node{Even natural talent is an unfair help}}
            }
        }
        child{node{Original position argument}}
    }
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the code to eliminate this problem?
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: What happened to the preamble of your document? (The answer is that you need to adjust the font size of the `child` nodes.)

Comment: I didn't put the preamble because I didn't think it was relevant. If you mean that in the node I have to write child[font size=20] I tried it and it doesn't work.
Also I would have to write it for all the nodes and it looks way too much work.
Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses `every node/.append style={font=\normalsize}`, makes a few more cosmetic changes, and has a preamble. Yes, preambles are important to attract others to look at your problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, 
concept color=blue!10, 
    level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45},
    level 3/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45,
    text width=1.5cm,minimum size=2.25cm},
    level 4/.append style={level distance=3.5cm,sibling angle=45,
    text width=2cm,minimum size=3cm},
every node/.append style={font=\normalsize}]


\node{Rawls}
    child[concept color=red!60]{node{He's in opposition with}
        child{node{Utili\\-tarism}}
        child{node{Intui\\-tionism}}
    }
    child[concept color=blue!60]{node{Two main arguments}
        child{node{Intuitive argument}
            child{node{Equality of opportunity}
                child{node{Even natural talent is an unfair help}}
            }
        }
        child{node{Original position argument}}
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. Next time I'll put also the preamble of the document